# trouble with spring-hibernate3:jar:2.0.8 and struts2-core:jar:2.3.16 for different version of asm

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, struts2

I am working on a project for upgrade an application to spring 3.2.0.RELEASE, struts 2.3.16, and hibernate 3.6.5.Final.
in the pom.xml, I have dependency spring-hibernate3 2.0.8 version.

And, I found out this version need asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile, 
but, struts need asm 3.3 and 3.3.1.
Currently, when I try to start the application use Tomcat 7.0, I have issue with different asm version conflict issue.
The errors are:
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V

I can't upgrade the hibernate to 4, I have to stay in 3.6. 
So, I need introduce two version of asm, how to separate them and forbid them refer the wrong version of asm?

Comment: Never mix spring version. `spring-hibernate3.jar` is an old spring jar belonging to Spring 2.0. Remove it if you use a spring version higher then that. `spring-hibernate3.jar` is replaced by `spring-orm.jar`.

Comment: You are correct.  I fixed this and solve the problem.